# Get data after second query after inserting room data on android

Tags: android

I am using room persistence library for save some data and get these data.

Firstly I insert some data to room and after that I try to get inserted data in another fragment. But first time it is empty, after opening fragment second time it shows data. What I forget?

```
@Database(entities = {Cart.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
    public abstract CartDao m=CartDao();
    public static synchronized AppDatabase getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(ctx.getApplicationContext(),
                    AppDatabase.class, "db")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
                    .build();
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}


public class CartRepository {
    private Application application;
    private static CartRepository CartRepository;
    private CartDao mCartDao;

    private CartRepository(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
        AppDatabase db;
        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
        mCartDao = db.mCartDao();
    }
    public synchronized static CartRepository getInstance(Application application) {
        if (CartRepository == null) {
            CartRepository = new CartRepository(application);
        }
        return CartRepository;
    }
    public void addCart(Cart cart) {
        InsertAsyncTask task = new InsertAsyncTask(mCartDao);
        task.execute(cart);
    }
    public List<Cart> getCartList() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return new GetAllCartAsyncTask(mCartDao).execute().get();
    }
    private static class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Cart, Void, Void> {
        private CartDao asyncTaskDao;
        InsertAsyncTask(CartDao dao) {
            asyncTaskDao = dao;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Cart... result) {
            asyncTaskDao.addCart(result[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static class GetAllCartAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Cart>> {
        private CartDao asyncTaskDao;
        GetAllCartAsyncTask(CartDao dao) {
            asyncTaskDao = dao;
        }
        @Override
        protected List<Cart> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return asyncTaskDao.getCartList();
        }
    }
}
```

FirstFragment

```
mCartRepository = CartRepository.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication());
    mCartRepository .addCart(cart);
```

SecondFragment

```
mCartRepository = CartRepository.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication());
List<Cart> cartList = mCartRepository.getCartList();
// cartList.size is 0 after inserting, only after start fragment again it shows data
                if (cartList.size() > 0) {
                    mList.addAll(cartList);
                    item_id = cartList.get(0).getItem_id(); 
                }
```

Comment: What are you using these two fragments in? I am guessing you are using them in a ViewPager. Is that right?

Comment: Bottom navigationview

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this problem. There is a LiveData and ViewModel approach and there is a simple workaround approach. Which one would you like to try out?

Comment: Simple workaround approach

Comment: Then, please could you paste your Activity code, the one where you do the fragment populating and the SecondFragment code? And also I recommend not using AsyncTask as it has been deprecated.

Comment: can I send codes to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202334/discussion-between-ravi-and-benfactor).